# Publish azure functionapp using python in PyCharm

Tags: python, azure, pycharm, azure-functions

I have an azure function app which I use for simple testing purpose. In order to (semi-)automatically run some tests, I want to be able to automatically upload a set of function apps to azure from within a python script.

Therefore I `os.chdir()` into the corresponding folder and then try to run the publish command.

If I run the publish command manually (`func azure functionapp publish <name> --python --build remote`) everything works fine. However, If I call the command from within PyCharm I always get the error (here truncated)

```
The format of value 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiO...
' is invalid
```

My python code looks like this:

```py
import subprocess
import shutil

try:
    result = subprocess.run([
        shutil.which('func'),
        'azure', 'functionapp',
        'publish', azure_function_app_resource_name,
        '--python',
        '--build remote'
    ], text=True)
    if result.returncode > 0:
        print('Failed')
    else:
        print('OK')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Failed')
```

Before executing this I make sure the azure cli / core functions are available by running and evaluating the output of the following statements. This works flawlessly.

```
subprocess.run([shutil.which('az'), '--version'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
subprocess.run([shutil.which('func'), '--version'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

I can also get the appsettings of the function app without any problem in python, so it is not a problem of not being logged in:

```py
result = subprocess.run([
    shutil.which('az'), 'functionapp', 'config', 'appsettings', 'list',
    '--name', azure_function_app_resource_name,
    '--resource-group', azure_resource_group_name
], capture_output=True, text=True)
```

*Update*: This is on Windows 10, Python 3.7, PyCharm 2019.3.4

Does anyone have an idea or working code?

**Note**: I *am* aware that `azure.core.cli` exists, however, it is badly documented and does not help with the azure core function tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, PyCharm sets an environmental variable called `PYCHARM_HOSTED`. My inquiries suggest that it is used to identify whether a script is run from within PyCharm, but apparently it somehow influences the publishing process.

In order to successfully execute the build process, it can be deleted from within the python script prior to running the subprocess:

```py
import subprocess
import shutil
import os

if 'PYCHARM_HOSTED' in os.environ:
    # try/except would be more pythonic, but longer
    del os.environ['PYCHARM_HOSTED']
try:
    result = subprocess.run([
        shutil.which('func'),
        'azure', 'functionapp',
        'publish', azure_function_app_resource_name,
        '--python',
        '--build remote'
    ], text=True)
    if result.returncode > 0:
        print('Failed')
    else:
        print('OK')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Failed')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import subprocess
print(u'Test Beginning!')
input('input:')
os.system('func azure functionapp publish yourfunctionname --force')
input('input:')
print(u'Test Endding!')
```

This code works fine on my side, please have a try.(run the script in the function folder.)

Comment: Fails with the identical error. I should (maybe) have noted that I use windows...

Comment: @Timm Yes, I am also win10 python3.7. Can you show the screenshot of the error? On my side it is no problem.

Comment: @Timm This is the screenshot on my side: [The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCSgd.png). You can see that it works fine, so win10 and python3.7 is not the reason.

Comment: Okay, I tried some things, turns out if I call `python publish.py` from the cmd, it works just fine, if I start it from within PyCharm it fails. so maybe something about the environment, but apparently a totally different problem.
I will think about how to rephrase the question. Thank you so far.

Comment: FYI: I rephrased it slightly and added my own answer. It was the environment, although the variable I least expected to influence things: `PYCHARM_HOSTED`.

Comment: @Timm Thanks for your contribution.